# Number of customers that shop in both Store A and B in Python

Tags: python

I would like to see how many customers are shopping amongst different stores.

For example,

[image: Shoppers]

2000 unique customers shop in Store A and B only
1500 unique customers shop in Store A, B and C only
200 unique customers shop in B and C only

Can this be done?

[image: Code]

Above is what I attempted using another code I saw online but it does not provide me with actual names of the company. So, I would like to see what 2 companies do 9.5K customers shop between.

Comment: Please, provide actual code instead of images.

Comment: yes it can be done.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
ser = (df.groupby("Customer")['Store'].unique()
           .apply(sorted)
           .apply('|'.join)
           .value_counts())
```

The resulting series `ser`:

```
A|B      4
B        4
A        4
A|B|C    3
A|C      3
C        1
B|C      1
Name: Store, dtype: int64
```

The starting dataframe `df`:

```
    Customer Store
0          1     B
1          1     A
2          2     C
3          2     B
4          2     A
5          3     B
6          4     B
7          4     A
8          5     A
9          6     C
10         6     A
11         7     B
12         7     A
13         8     A
14         9     B
15         9     A
16        10     B
17        11     A
18        12     C
19        12     B
20        12     A
21        13     B
22        14     C
23        14     A
24        15     C
25        15     A
26        16     C
27        17     A
28        18     C
29        18     B
30        19     C
31        19     B
32        19     A
33        20     B
```